# Vaadin 14 TreeGrid - Cannot add the same item multiple times

Tags: vaadin, treegrid

Working on a project that will display hierarchies of "tasks". I'm running into a problem where it will not allow for multiple entries of the same object. From what I can tell, the "duplicate" item is under a different parent.

The domain data allows for this - a given task may appear in lots of places.

It would seem that this is intentional (maybe), but is there a way around this?

Comment: You will have an uphill battle, if your equals/hashcode does not produce unique things. Vaadin needs this to map between the JS and the Java world. I'd use a POJO and make parent+todo or even path-to-todo+todo the identity.  If the same todo can be even under the same parent multiple times, I'd go with whatever the end user would use to know them apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's intentional to a degree; each Grid and TreeGrid data item is expected to be unique. You could work around this by creating your own implementation of the hierarchical DataProvider class (for example extend `AbstractHierarchicalDataProvider`) which overrides the `getId` method along with the other required methods. The return value of this method needs to be unique per item, as it's used as a hash key.

Comment: I'd say it's fully intentional. Any other design would lead to lots of complexity for methods that would deal with e.g. the selected or expanded state of a specific row. If duplicates would be allowed in different parts of the hierarchy, then all those methods would have to be based on the full hierarchy path rather than only the leaf node.

Comment: Rather than messing with `getId`, one could also consider introducing a wrapper type as the actual item.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is probably not the best solution, but it works.
I added a field to the abstract super class that is initialized with the current time (long ms). When I am adding items to the tree grid, I check to see if the tree contains the item and if so, I randomize the field and then add it. The new field is marked `@Transient` so it's not persisted.